# A better chi-square test for Perl?

Tags: perl, statistics

Let's say I roll a 6-sided die 60 times and I get 16, 5, 9, 7, 6, 15 roles for the numbers 1 through 6, respectively. The numbers 1 and 6 are showing up too much and [there's only about a  1.8% chance of that being random](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/qmss/the_chisquare_test/about_the_chisquare_test.html). If I use [Statistics::ChiSquare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-ChiSquare/), it prints out:

```
There's a >1% chance, and a <5% chance, that this data is random.
```

So not only is it a bad interface (I can't get those numbers back directly), but the rounding error is significant.

What's worse, what if I'm rolling 2 six sided dice? The odds of getting any particular number are:

```
Sum Frequency   Relative Frequency 
2   1           1/36 
3   2           2/36                                                                                                                                                                                                               
4   3           3/36
5   4           4/36
6   5           5/36
7   6           6/36
8   5           5/36
9   4           4/36
10  3           3/36
11  2           2/36
12  1           1/36
```

[Statistics::ChiSquare used to have a chisquare_nonuniform() function](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JONO/Statistics-ChiSquare-0.1/ChiSquare.pm), but it was removed.

So the numbers are rounded poorly and I can't use it for a non-uniform distribution. Given a list of actual frequency and a list of expected frequency, what's the best way of calculating the chi-square test in Perl? The various modules I'm finding on the CPAN aren't helping me, so I'm guessing I missed something obvious.

Comment: The chi squared test is simple enough mathematically to implement directly in maybe 20 lines of code, and I expect most people wanting more direct control will do just that. The error bounds for 1%, 5% etc are more difficult to calculate, so simple utils will probably just hard-code the P < 0.01, P < 0.05 etc values. I would not be too surprised to find a better chi squared test in a generic stats module like http://search.cpan.org/~mikek/Statistics-Distributions-1.02/Distributions.pm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implementing this yourself is so simple that I wouldn't want to upload Yet Another Statistics Module just for this.

```
use Carp qw< croak >;
use List::Util qw< sum >;
use Statistics::Distributions qw< chisqrprob >;

sub chi_squared_test {
  my %args = @_;
  my $observed = delete $args{observed} // croak q(Argument "observed" required);
  my $expected = delete $args{expected} // croak q(Argument "expected" required);
  @$observed == @$expected or croak q(Input arrays must have same length);

  my $chi_squared = sum map {
    ($observed->[$_] - $expected->[$_])**2 / $expected->[$_];
  } 0 .. $#$observed;
  my $degrees_of_freedom = @$observed - 1;
  my $probability = chisqrprob($degrees_of_freedom, $chi_squared);
  return $probability;
}

say chi_squared_test
  observed => [16, 5, 9, 7, 6, 17],
  expected => [(10) x 6];
```

Output: `0.018360`

Comment: amon, thank you. That's perfect. I had tried implementing that myself, but I see that I had made a small math error in calculating `$chi_squared`. I appreciate your help!

Comment: And if you're curious, here's my write-up: http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2014/01/testing-random-dice-rolls.html

Comment: @amon: I hadn't seen the `delete x // croak` statement before. The [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) on `//` say that it returns a value that cannot be used as an lvalue. So how does `delete` work correctly here, since it should technically only be operating on a value here and not an lvalue?

Comment: @NateGlenn Precedence. As an unary operator, `delete` binds tighter than `//` which has the same precedence as `||`. I often use the above pattern to handle named arguments, the point being that I can later assert no other args were given: `croak "Unknown arguments ", (join ",", keys %args) if keys %args`.

Comment: I would be happy to see that on cpan ! Can help with that.